# using Async/await in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, jestjs

I have this test in Jest that throws an Exception and pass the test

```
await expect(hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier)).rejects.toThrow(FunctionalError);
```

but when I do

```
const action = async () => {
   await hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier);
};


expect(action).toThrowError(FunctionalError);
```

I have this result: `Received function did not throw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually call `action`, change it to:

```
it('should throw', async () => {
  await expect(action()).rejects.toThrowError(FunctionalError);
});
```